# Installing new GNOME 3.16 games in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: games, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 with GNOME 3.16. I am wondering if it is possible to install the new GNOME 3.16 games (including taquin) in Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game Taquin and all other games are not included in any PPA. If you want to install it, then you have to compile it yourself. [Here](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-taquin) is the source code.

Comment: ah, got it.  Thank you for the answer. I will compile from source then.